# Problem - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net, structuremap

I was trying to build a social networking site from *ASP.NET 3.5 Social Networking* book. When I run the code I see the following problems:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Fisharoo.FisharooWeb' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:
         {
             _view = view;
             _accountService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance();
             _redirector = ObjectFactory.GetInstance();
         }
```

and

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Fisharoo.FisharooWeb' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[StructureMapException: StructureMap Exception Code:  101
```

Hope it has simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an assembly file named Fisharoo.FisharooWeb.dll. Does the book have a companion CD/DVD, or a website where you can download the sample source code? Basically you need to get a copy of the missing file and put it in the bin folder of your website, or the global assembly cache (C:\Windows\Assembly), depending on the instructions given in the book.

Here's a [link](http://forum.socialnetworkingin.net/yaf_postst61_debuging-problem.aspx) that might help. Apparently the book's appendix has instructions on how to setup the code.

Hope this helps.